# Prometheus export data to AWS S3 periodically

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, prometheus

Is there any way to keep periodic backup of Prometheus Data programmatically ?
The requirement is something like following :

> Two containers viz C-1 & C-2 are continuously being monitored by our Prometheus Server P-1.
> This time-series DB needs to be backed-up, say in JSON format, once a day in AWS S3 - every day
> one new time-stamped JSON file created in AWS S3.
> Can't use 'Thanos' or other similar components. HTTP End-point to query all required metrics
> are available.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Backups to S3 can be performed from Prometheus snapshots - see [this article](https://www.robustperception.io/taking-snapshots-of-prometheus-data). Prometheus doesn't provide a tool for making periodic snapshots and backups, so you need to write it on yourself. Another solution is to use Prometheus-like system, which provides such a tool for backups - see [this post](https://valyala.medium.com/speeding-up-backups-for-big-time-series-databases-533c1a927883).

Comment: Thanks for your comment and time. I am looking for some streaming solution, something where Prometheus data as generated gets streamed to kafka broker and from there using S3 kafka connect gets saved to S3. Was just thinking, if it's even possible. Has something similar been achieved earlier ?

Comment: It is possible to set up [vmagent](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/vmagent.html) in front of Prometheus, so it could scrape targets and stream the collected data to both Prometheus and Kafka. See [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/vmagent.html#kafka-integration).